# A misunderstanding on taglist vim plugin

Tags: linux, vim

It seems like I do not understand how to make taglist show new functions on the fly.

I have something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   some code here;
}
```

Taglist would show the main function.

But than I edit the file, and the code in the buffer goes like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function(int x, int y);

int function(int x,int y)
{
    some code here;
}

int main()
{
    some code here;
}
```

Taglist would only show new function after saving and reopeneing file, :TlistUpdate would not help.

So the question is how do I make taglist show newly written functions, if possible - automatically and if possible - even when buffer is not saved yet?

I believe it's rather software issue than development question, hence superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved; I added the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.c :TlistUpdate
```

According to taglist's FAQ, ctags can only work with file existing on disc, so updating taglist on unsaved buffer would not do anything.

Automatic update is possible, and showing new functions in unsaved buffer is not.